# Concatenating positions into genomic segments

Tags: r, concatenation, bioinformatics, bioconductor, genome

I would like to concatenate all rows which have more than `0.955` of similarity score. The `Abo`and `Bel` columns represents the similarity score with above and below rows, respectively. In the following input `df` I have 10 genomic probes (`NAME` column) which is concatenated in just 4 genomic segments (`dfout`).

```
df <- " NAME Abo  Bel Chr GD Position
 BovineHD0100009217 NA 1.0000000   1  0  31691781
 BovineHD0100009218 1.0000000 0.6185430   1  0  31695808
 BovineHD0100019600 0.6185430 0.9973510   1  0  69211537
 BovineHD0100019601 0.9973510 1.0000000   1  0  69213650
 BovineHD0100019602 1.0000000 1.0000000   1  0  69214650
 BovineHD0100019603 1.0000000 0.6600000   1  0  69217942
 BovineHD0100047112 0.6600000 1.0000000   1  0  93797691
 BovineHD0100026604 1.0000000 1.0000000   1  0  93815774
 BovineHD0100026605 1.0000000 0.4649007   1  0  93819471
 BovineHD0100029861 0.4649007 NA   1  0 105042452"
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

My expected output `dfout`:

```
dfout <- "Chr start end startp endp nprob 
           1  31691781 31695808 BovineHD0100009217 BovineHD0100009218 2
           1  69211537 69217942 BovineHD0100019600 BovineHD0100019603 4
           1  93797691 93819471 BovineHD0100047112 BovineHD0100026605 3
           1  105042452 105042452 BovineHD0100029861 BovineHD0100029861 1"
dfout <- read.table(text=dfout, header=T)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Side question, what function did you use to get probes' similarity score?

Comment: Genotype similarity between subsequent probes in a given animal from a given population. Approach to infer genomic segments (CNV alelle) which harbor probes with very similar genotype distribuition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't think of any pretty solution using basic dataframe manipulation, so here's a bad-looking one that works:

First, add `stringsAsFactors` to `df` creation:

```
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

start <- df$Position[1]
end <- integer()
output <- NULL
count <- 1
for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)) {
  if(df$Bel[i] < 0.955)  {
    end <- df$Position[i]
    output <- rbind(output, c(start, end, df$NAME[which(df$Position == start)], df$NAME[which(df$Position == end)], count))
    start <- df$Position[i+1]
    count <- 0
  } 
  count <- count + 1
}
end <- df$Position[nrow(df)]
output <- as.data.frame(rbind(output, c(start, end, df$NAME[which(df$Position == start)], df$NAME[which(df$Position == end)], count)))
colnames(output) <- c("start", "end", "startp", "endp", "nprob")
```

The basic idea here is looping through the rows and checking if the next should be added to the current segment (`Bel > 0.955`) or if a new segment should start (`Bel <= 0.955`). When a new sequence has to be started, the endrow is defined, the respective row added to the output and the new starting segment also defined. A `count` is used to add the number of rows used to create the segment (`nprob`).

Finally the last segment is added, outside the for loop, and the output receives its column names and is converted to a dataframe. I did not use `Chr` because 1. They are all equal, 2. if they weren't you didn't give any way to choose/summarize them.

Result:

```
> output
      start       end             startp               endp nprob
1  31691781  31695808 BovineHD0100009217 BovineHD0100009218     2
2  69211537  69217942 BovineHD0100019600 BovineHD0100019603     4
3  93797691  93819471 BovineHD0100047112 BovineHD0100026605     3
4 105042452 105042452 BovineHD0100029861 BovineHD0100029861     1
```

I'm pretty sure that you or someone else can work on this to make it shorter and more concise.

Answer (score 2):

Here is `dplyr` version. First we need to define groups, that is what `mutate` bit is doing, then simple `summarise` function within the groups.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
   Abo955=ifelse(Abo<0.955,NA,Abo),
   myGroup=cumsum(is.na(Abo955)*1)) %>%
  group_by(myGroup) %>% 
  summarise(
    Chr=min(Chr),
    start=min(Position),
    end=max(Position),
    startp=first(NAME),
    lastp=last(NAME),
    nprob=n()) %>% 
  select(-myGroup)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is purely based on logical vectors and works with the provided example.

As Molx said, let's add stringsAsFactors=F

```
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T, stringAsFactors = F)
```

An just so that the logical evaluations work let's change NA to 0s

```
df(is.na(df)) <- 0
```

Now, for the consecutive rows that will be concatenated lets find the "start" and "end" rows using logical evaluations

```
starts <- df$Bel >= 0.955 &  df$Abo < 0.955
ends <- df$Bel < 0.955 &  df$Abo >= 0.955
```

With this we  can already construct a data.frame concatenating rows that need to be concatenated

```
concatenated <- data.frame(Chr = df[starts, "Chr"], 
                            start = df[starts, "Position"], 
                            end = df[ends, "Position"],
                            startp = df[starts, "NAME"],
                            endp = df[ends, "NAME"],
                            nprob = c( diff (which(starts))[1]  ,diff (which(ends)))
                            )
```

And let's also construct a data.frame with the rows that are not concatenated, i.e. the ones that do not have the desired similarity score with neither the above nor below row

```
notConcatenate <- df$Abo < 0.955 & df$Bel < 0.955

non_concatenated <- data.frame(Chr = df[notConcatenate, "Chr"], 
                            start = df[notConcatenate, "Position"], 
                            end = df[notConcatenate, "Position"],
                            startp = df[notConcatenate, "NAME"],
                            endp = df[notConcatenate, "NAME"],
                            nprob = 1
                            )
```

And finally bind the two data.frames

```
dfout <- rbind(concataneted,non_concatenated)
```

Resulting in

```
> dfout
  Chr     start       end             startp               endp nprob
1   1  31691781  31695808 BovineHD0100009217 BovineHD0100009218     2
2   1  69211537  69217942 BovineHD0100019600 BovineHD0100019603     4
3   1  93797691  93819471 BovineHD0100047112 BovineHD0100026605     3
4   1 105042452 105042452 BovineHD0100029861 BovineHD0100029861     1
```

NOTE: This code assumes that correlated probes are within the same chromosome

Cheers!